# Using ng-repeat with keys in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an object, simulating a Cassandra database, where I retrieve its data to display it on a AngularJs app. Unfortunately, I can't make a premade header for my array because the keys are subject to change, depending on the data I'll retrieve (Here's an example of what I'm talking about):

```
var columnFamilyData = {
  "DocInfo": {
    "4c58abf5": {
      "name": "coucou",
      "extension": "pdf",
      "size": 8751,
      "type": "facture",
      "repository": "archive"
    },
    "8cd524d7a45de": {
      "name": "gerard",
      "extension": "xml",
      "size": 48734,
      "type": "compta",
    },
    "5486d684fe54a": {
      "name": "splendide",
      "extension": "tiff",
      "type": "photos",
      "METADATA_A": "jambon"
    }
  },
  "Base": {
    "BASE_A": {
      "name": "BASE_A",
      "description": "That base is truly outrageous, they are truly, truly outrageous",
      "baseMetadata_1": "METADATA_A",
      "baseMetadata_2": "METADATA_B",
      "baseMetadata_3": "METADATA_C"
    },
  },
}
```

As you can see, the arrays in `DocInfo` and `Base` are different, data and keys.

What I want to do is being able to use my `ng-repeat` to create a `<th>` line with the key name (for instance, `Extension`, of `METADATA_A`), but only once, since `ng-repeat` may duplicate this information.

I'm also providing a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EKtn5/), if it can help any of you to understand my goal.

Thanks for reading and/or answering, have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is not totally clear, but it seems like you want `"(key, val) in object"` [syntax](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

```
ng-repeat="(name, age) in {'adam':10, 'amalie':12}"
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry I wasn't really clear. I tried this already. But I'm getting the object "columnFamilyData" to be transformed in an array using my controller (linked in the pastebin below). So when I'm using ng-repeat on key in my array, it does not return all the keys, and not in the proper order.

http://pastebin.com/DLwH0EzN

Comment: Create a working fiddle please. It's too hard without seeing it working.

Comment: I hard several js files to include, and not used to jsFiddle. Sorry.

To make it short: I want to return the keys in the selected array. For instance, for 4c58abf5 I want to retrieve "name", "extension", "size", "type", "repository' without having to check all my object.

Comment: What do you mean 'check all object'? To get keys, for example, via loDash you can `<div ng-repeat="(key, row) in columnFamilyData.DocInfo" ng-init="rowKeys = getKeys(row);"><span ng-repeat="rowKey in rowKeys" ng-bind="rowKey"></span></div>` and `$scope.getKeys = function(obj){ return _.keys(obj); };`